# DOM Element object identified as an "instanceof" multiple classes - all at once

Tags: java, gwt

A bit of context: I've been playing with uiBinder recently in an attempt to improve our approach to layout and reduce the number of Widgets our code relies on. As part of that, I'm trying to use HTML as opposed to Widgets as much as possible, and I decided to test event bubbling to dispatch child events to a parent widget where possible.

I proceeded to attach a Dom event handler to my parent widget, with the idea to handle events based on the type of html element that sourced the event which I would test for using **instanceof**.

My uiBinder code looks like this:

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" ui:field = "input0"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<div>Click Me please</div>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

And the class implementation:

```
public class MyWidget extends Composite {
  private static MyWidgetUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MyWidgetUiBinder.class);
  interface MyWidgetUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, MyWidget> {}
  @UiField
  InputElement input0;
  public MyWidget() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    super.addDomHandler(new ClickHandler(){

      @Override
      public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        System.out.print("Hi");
        Element el = Element.as(event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget());
        if(el instanceof InputElement){
          Window.alert("It is an INPUT ELEMENT");
        }
        if(el instanceof SpanElement){
          Window.alert("It is a SPAN!");
        }
        if(el instanceof DivElement){
          Window.alert("NO, it is a DIV!!!");
        }
      }
    }, ClickEvent.getType());
}
```

Now, what happens when I display on MyWidget is something I cannot understand. A click to both the text box and the div, or anywhere within the region of MyWidget results in ALL of the conditions in the click handler to be satisfied. All window alerts show up.

What's the reason for this, and how can I work around this issue? It must be something within GWT and the way it maps to HTML elements.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that `onClick` is not called several times?

Comment: Yeah, that's what the System.out.println("Hi") is for :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to use of [overlay types](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/OverlayTypes) in the GWT/DOM mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `clickEvent.getSource()`. It'll give you the Object that is the source of your event.

Comment: The code I have already gets a handle of the source object correctly. getSource() actually returns the current instance of MyWidget. I believe this is due to the event bubbling approach - the MyWidget instance is considered the source, and the target is the element that caused it. In any case, my question is why/how can multiple instanceof queries be satisfied by the same object..

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of event bubbling.
What you are doing is listening for low level DOM events on the element of HTMLPanel (that could be a div or span, for example). The reason that you are getting the click event for `input` elements within `HTMLPanel` could be that these events are bubbling up from the `input` element through the container hierarchy.

To make sure this understanding is correct, put a breakpoint in your `onClick` method to see if it is called more than once.

The workaround will be to use the GWT's high-level events instead of low level DOM events. In your case you will need to use [addClickHandler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/HasClickHandlers.html) on appropriate container widget.

Comment: It is precisely due to event bubbling - as that is the intent. Google suggests this approach to improve event handling performance by handling all events of interest through a single handler. The handler is called only once, and it is possible to identify the source object. What I am unclear on is why multiple "instanceof" conditions can be satisfied.

Comment: Are you sure multiple `instanceof` checks are being satisfied in a single invocation of your handler? Or could it be that the handler is being called several times, and each time a different `instanceof` check is succeeding?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, that was one of the first things I checked. You can try the code yourself, that's why I added a simplified example..